# Calling framework 4.0 from 3.5 framework

Tags: asp.net

I have an http module  written in Framework 4.0 I am saving the value in cookies. I am calling the http module in framework 3.5, is it possible to do like this? What things should be taken into account while doing this?

Comment: Unless you use some 4.0 specific features in your module, there shouldn't be any difference in using it in 3.5..

Comment: In the Http MOdule i am using few specific features of 4.0 frame work thats the reason wanted to know  how will this impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have written a module using .NET 4.0 specific features then how do you expect it to work in a framework without those features?

You can't access 4.0 features in a 3.5 application.